# Strange DateTime conversion behaviour

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a large csv file and each row has a date and a minute entry;

20000530,172700

And these two strings are supposed to represent May 30th 2000 17:27

C# won't convert this to a DateTime off top so I tried to use a custom pattern

```
string datePattern = "yyyymmdd";
DateTime.TryParseExact(d, datePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dateTest);

string timePattern = "hhmmss";
DateTime.TryParseExact(t, timePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out timeTest);
```

Whilst C# in theory converts these to DateTime objects, it doesn't actually work.

The time in the timeTest object is almost always 00:00 until it randomly decides it isn't.

The dateTest increments the day but not the month, it's constantly January (each file is it's own year so I don't know if it'd increment the year correctly).

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `yyyyMMdd` instead of `yyyymmdd` and `HHmmss` instead of `hhmmss` - [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks, copied how to do it from MS website but I don't think they mentioned the capitalisation bit.

Comment: `hh` The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12 [The "hh" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#hhSpecifier) - `HH` The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23 [The "HH" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#HH_Specifier)

Answer (score 1):

Capital MM and HH fixes your issue

```
string dateString = "20000530,172700";

  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd,HHmmss", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime result))
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Parsed DateTime: " + result);
  }
  else
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse the DateTime.");
  }
```

You can break down the resulting datetime object as needed